# Print specific word in python

Tags: python

I have a file 'out' with data

```
cell (XOR4DGHFDH22DSVT) {
cell (ND2DGH557GGHDSVT) {
cell (SDK1DNG45GKDSVT) {
```

I want output to be

```
XOR4DGHFDH22DSVT 
ND2DGH557GGHDSVT
SDK1DNG45GKDSVT
```

I want to get this output using Python 2.7.5 in another file.

I tried using `re.findall()` and `split()` but could not get it.
code I used is:

```
c2= open("out1", 'w')

file1= open("out","r")
for c in file1:
  split_lines = c.split(" ")
  print(split_lines[1]) >> c2
```

Comment: You should provide the code you tried to use so we can indicate where to make improvements.

Comment: what does this mean? `could not get it`

Comment: Vikas, in order to edit (and etc) your post, you'll want to log back in to [your account](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/433888/vikas-choudhary?tab=profile).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Python [re module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) and positive look-behind, so that we find the string prior to the match, but don't consume it for the result.

Find all matches into the input file and print them line by line to the output file:

```py
import re

with open('input_file.txt', 'r') as f:
    m = re.findall('(?<=cell \()[^)]*', f.read())
    
with open('output_file.txt', 'w') as f:
    for x in m:
        f.write(x+"\n")
```

Here is some explanation of the regex:

```
                '(?<=   cell \(  ) [^)]*'
positive look-behind=   -------    match all to the next closing parenthesis
```

You can modify the regex to a more strict form:

```
'(?<=cell \()[^)]*(?=\) {)'
```

if you want to use look-ahead also, to demand explicitly the `) {` after any match.

### Testing

```
> cat input_file.txt 
cell (XOR4DGHFDH22DSVT) {
    test(test)
}
cell (ND2DGH557GGHDSVT) {
cell (SDK1DNG45GKDSVT) {
> python3 test.py 
> cat output_file.txt 
XOR4DGHFDH22DSVT
ND2DGH557GGHDSVT
SDK1DNG45GKDSVT
```

Comment: Tested with python2 also good (I see the question was edited with a previous version)

Comment: Thanks . This worked.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ python3 -c 'import sys
with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
  for l in f:
    a, b = map(lambda x: l.find(x), ["(",")"])
    print(l[a+1:b])
' out > out1

$ cat out1
XOR4DGHFDH22DSVT
ND2DGH557GGHDSVT
SDK1DNG45GKDSVT
```

- the idiomatic way / pythonic way is to use the `with-open` clause as it automatically closes the file descriptor at eof and also takes care of errors in open.
- record the positions in the current line of the characters `(` and `)`  and use the string slice notation to pluck out the cellname.
- Assuming that `)`  doesn't occur before `(`

Comment: Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

you can chain the various split operations to get the cellname.

```
python3 -c '
import sys 
with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
  for l in f:
    print(l.split("(")[1].split(")")[0]) 
' input_file
XOR4DGHFDH22DSVT
ND2DGH557GGHDSVT
SDK1DNG45GKDSVT
```

Comment: `.split()[1].rpartition("(")[2].partition(")")[0]` to handle the case of missing parentheses

Comment: @iruvar Thanks for the great tip! You are a python pro.